# split python string if newline starts with a period

Tags: python, regex, string

I try to split a text where a newline starts with only a period.

```
txt = "\ra. skin lateral biopsy:\r -positive for disease \r.\rb. skin medial biopsy:\r -negative for disease \r. \rc. skin floor biopsy:\r -negative for disease"
```

the expected result would be:

```
["a. skin lateral biopsy: -positive for disease", "b. skin medial biopsy: -negative for disease", "c. skin floor biopsy: -negative for disease"]
```

I tried

```
re.split('^\.', txt) and it does not work.
```

I don't understand what why regex is not picking up the lines that start with periods.

Comment: If there aren't spaces before the period; you can just use split `print(txt.split('\r.'))`

Comment: Like `re.split(r"\n\.")` or `re.split(r"^\.")`

Comment: Why don't you write these answers as ... well as answers? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments

Comment: totally right. I guess i was making it harder than it needed to be lol

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would split the text, and then I would process it through a loop

```
txt = "\ra. skin lateral biopsy:\r -positive for disease \r.\rb. skin medial biopsy:\r -negative for disease \r. \rc. skin floor biopsy:\r -negative for disease";
arr = txt.split("\r.")
for j in arr:
  j = j.replace("\r", "") 
  j = j.strip()
  print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[re.sub(r'\r.?','',e).strip() for e in re.split(r'\r(?=[a-z])',txt) if e]

['a. skin lateral biopsy:-positive for disease', 'b. skin medial biopsy:-negative for disease', 'c. skin floor biopsy:-negative for disease']
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand what why regex is not picking up the lines that start with periods.

`^` means assert start of string unless in multiline mode when it means assert start of line, so the following would work if your `txt` contained newlines `\n`.

```py
re.split('^\.', txt, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

You could either replace the `\r` in `txt` with `\n` or just use one of the following:

```py
# Keep the \r that come before a period
re.split('(?<=\r)\.', txt)

# Remove the \r that come before a period
re.split('\r\.', txt)
```